# Windows 10 OS not letting me open Minecraft launcher offline

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, windows-10, minecraft-launcher

Anytime my internet goes down, I still want to play Minecraft. On a Windows 11 laptop I can access my Minecraft launcher even when I don't have a connection; however, on Windows 10 (a different PC), it just raises an error on a different window and not only doesn't even allow me to play, but it doesn't even open the launcher.

Is there a way to access Minecraft offline on Windows 10, or am I just screwed?

**Note**: I do not want to use cracked or pirated Minecraft launchers.

## Error

[image: error]

Comment: Interesting that the different OS'es seem to change this - unless is there some sort of configuration for the launcher you can modify?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, there is no setting for this in the launcher...

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: IDK remember atm, but I will add that sometime soon (i'm really busy this weekend)

Comment: Not recommend but some CRACKED Minecraft launchers can run without Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try going to Microsoft store, click on your user account icon (top-right), settings, and turn on `Offline Permissions`. Make sure that you have installed all the latest windows updates on your computer before doing this.

[Source](https://www.auslogics.com/en/articles/play-minecraft-offline-in-windows-10-11/)